# JUnit Test of Code that uses GAE/J URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService()

Tags: java, google-app-engine, junit, urlfetch

I've got some code I'm deploying to Google App Engine - Java (GAE/J) that makes use of the `URLFetchService`.    I'd like to use JUnit to test this code.   Per the [testing documentation,](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting.html#Introducing_App_Engine_Utilities) it appears I should have a test that uses their `LocalURLFetchServiceTestConfig` class ROUGHLY as follows:

```
public class MyRemoteServiceTests {
    private static final LocalURLFetchServiceTestConfig urlConfig = new LocalURLFetchServiceTestConfig();
    private static final LocalServiceTestHelper helper = 
        new LocalServiceTestHelper(urlConfig);
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        service = new SampleService();
        helper.setUp();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        service = null;
        helper.tearDown();
    }

    @Test
    public void testThatCallsCodeThatUsesUrlFetch() {
            Object data = service.getRemoteDataUsingUrlFetch("foo", "bar");
            Assert.assertNotNull(data);
    }

}
```

I'm finding that this test continues to fail despite using the "helper" as suggested in the GAE/J documentation on testing: "`The API package 'urlfetch' or call 'Fetch()' was not found.`".

I was assuming that using the "helper" would somehow setup the GAE environment such that when I call `URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService()` from within my `getRemoteDataUsingUrlFetch` method, the interface returned would be an instance of `LocalURLFetchService` that would just "work" but that seems NOT to be the case.

- How can I test this code?
- Am I missing something?  (I'm pretty new to GAE...)
- Do I have to refactor my `getRemoteDataUsingUrlFetch` so that it doesn't use `URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService()` because that makes it untestable locally???  (That sounds like it would really suck...)

Any help/suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it turns out my problem was failure to include two additional jars that ARE mentioned on the [Local Unit Testing](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting.html) page of the documentation.  RTM FTW!

- appengine-local-runtime.jar
- appengine-api-stubs.jar

Comment: Glad you figured that one out. My earlier answer was probably off target :(

Answer (score 0):

afaik, the LocalURLFetchService doesn't configure the GAE like you expect. It is more of a way to fetch URL from the local dev and then process the contents however. (Similarly even the LocalDatastoreService and LocalMemcacheService operate on isolated spaces within the test environment) 
One way to test your code is to refactor the getRemoteDataUsingUrlFetch() to take maybe the contents of the Url response. somewhat like,

```
URLFetchResponse resp = LocalURLFetchService.fetch(status, request)

getRemoteDataUsingUrlFetch(foo, bar, resp)
```

Comment: Hmm... that's what I was a little worried about.   Any good way to detect whether code is running in the "real" GAE environment or not so that I could possible write a simple interface around URLFetchService and transparently use the appropriate implementation?

Comment: To detect whether you are running on the dev or "real" environment check the system property var 'com.google.appengine.runtime.environment'. this will be either 'Production' or 'Development' . Also see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Environment

Comment: Thanks!  However, it looks like the idea of abstracting the different URL fetch implementations behind an interface may not even be that trivial...  it looks like they don't even share similar method signatures...  [link](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/dev/LocalURLFetchService.html#fetch(Status, URLFetchRequest) "fetch - local")   [fetch - prod](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/URLFetchService.html#fetch(com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest))

Comment: Turns out I'm an idiot and didn't read the documentation closely enough and missed the fact that I needed to add to additional jars to my classpath... doh!   See my answer below.